# Установка компонентов .NET Framework 4.5

Tags: .net, sharepoint

Для установки *SharedPoint Server 2013* на *Windows 7* необходимо выполнить несколько несложных действий (по [инструкции](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2014/08/21/guest-blog-by-jonas-nilsson-install-sharepoint-2013-on-windows-7-8-8-1.aspx)).

Одним из шагов является установка некоторых компонентов *.NET Framework 4.5/WCF*, однако подобного пункта в *"Windows Features"* у меня нет (*.NET Framework 4.5* установлен).

[.NET Framework 4.5 Advanced Services/WCF Services http://community.bamboosolutions.com/resized-image.ashx/__size/725x0/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/sharepoint-2013/SharePoint-2013-on-Windows-8-_2D00_-18.PNG](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/resized-image.ashx/__size/725x0/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/sharepoint-2013/SharePoint-2013-on-Windows-8-_2D00_-18.PNG)

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Что вы делаете не так: ставите приложение на неподдерживаемую ось. Это уже изначально неправильно. Также см. первоисточник http://www.disruptivei.com/Blogg/Inlägg/6/Install-SharePoint-2013-on-Windows-7-8-8-1 — там сказано: "UPDATE: **This installer will only work on Win8+ don't try it on Win7**". Что как бы намекает, что на семёрке не будет работать даже этот костыльный способ.

Comment: @Discord, и заголовок "Install SharePoint 2013 on Windows 7/8/8.1". ))

Comment: Не читайте дурацких "How To" из непонятных блогов. Просто запустите установщик SharePoint - он сам в процессе установки поставит все необходимые зависимости.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov, Сам он не поставит т.к. на Windows 7/8/8.1 он вообще ставиться не должен)

Comment: @SergeyRufanov Это значит, что содержимое разошлось с заголовком. Такое бывает.

Comment: @user3239600, ага.. и именно поэтому эти ОС перечислены в требованиях для "Developer Workstation" )) А предупреждение конфигуратора о том, что "установка SharePoint на Windows Vista и Windows 7 предназначена только только для разработки, а не для продакшена" - Microsoft видимо добавила по просьбе автора блога ) Повторюсь - у меня нормально ставилась на 7-ку по официальной инструкции с диска, и вполне себе работало )

Comment: @SergeyRufanov sharepoint 2010? Там это действительно указано.

Comment: @user3239600, да, именно 2010. в 2012 ещё ставил на свою машину(тогда эта версия была последней) -  как-раз для целей "пощупать, что да как", и если что - использовать для разработки. Потом уже конечно выделили нормальный сервер. Жаль только пользователей так и не смогли к нему приучить (

Comment: @SergeyRufanov к сожалению, установка sharepoint 2013 на Windows 7/8 не предусмотрена официально, а установочник просто сообщает об этом и автоматически завершается.

Answer (score 2):

Вы должны скачать эти компоненты отдельно и установить.
Полный список необходимых компонентов есть [здесь](http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2012/12/26/install-and-download-sharepoint-2013-prerequisites-offline-manually.aspx).